# How to sum multiple columns ending a certain word and keep summing in a new column?

Tags: pandas

```
Date    A ZONE_GEN  A ZONE_LOAD  B ZONE_GEN  A ZONE_LOAD
1-1-2010     20             15          30            25
1-2-2010     30             25          40            35
....         ...            ...         ...           ...
1-12-2010    15             20          20            14
```

I want to create two new columns having names "Gen" and "LOAD" then sum each column ending with "Gen" in GEN column
likewise column ending with Load
I would like to get output as below:

```
Date      Gen   Load
1-1-2010  50     45
1-2-2010  70     60 
...
1-12-2010 35     34
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def f(c):
    return c.rsplit('_', 1)[1]

df.set_index('Date').groupby(f, axis=1).sum().reset_index()

        Date  GEN  LOAD
0   1-1-2010   50    40
1   1-2-2010   70    60
2  1-12-2010   35    34
```